# How to find the derivative of $g(x)$ under this kind of situation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose we have $g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{d(u,x)} du$ where $g,f,d$ are all functions.
How can we find the derivative of $g(x)$ under this situation

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you do not tell, what kind of functions $f$ and $d$ are, no answer is possible !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the conditions for derivation under the integral sign are fulfilled,

$$\frac d{dx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(u)}{d(u, x)}du=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac\partial{\partial x}\frac{f(u)}{d(u, x)}du=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\partial d(u,x)}{\partial x}\frac{f(u)}{d^2(u, x)}du.$$